# FileNotFoundException using JAR command to unzip WAR in Batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, filenotfoundexception

Running Java 1.8.0_141.  Also ran into problem with 1.8.0_121.  I

Running the following command to extract contents of a WAR into a temp directory:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jar -xvf ..\petclinic_sdk.war
```

The petclinic_sdk sample project that I'm using can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic

It seems to extract everything correctly, but then appears to try extracting the libraries contained within the WAR.  I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
 (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:261)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)
```

That JAR lives in /temp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar after the extraction.

The problem is I need the temp directory to be clean of temporary files.  Because it appears to be trying to extract those JARs as well, /temp is full of jartmp******************.tmp files: [temp directory after extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmQB1.png)

Thoughts?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Java 1.8.0_25. That `jar` command is not recursive. You must be using a different command line.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.  My loop containing the above code was recursive.

Working code here:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%i in (*) do (
   if %%~xi == .jar (
        rem ...
   )
   if %%~xi == .war (
       set foo=%%~ni%.war
       mkdir temp
       cd temp
       %JAVA_HOME%\bin\jar -xvf ..\!foo! 
       rem ...
   )

   if %%~xi == .ear (
        rem ...
   )
)
```